# Discount combination table

Tags: php, mysql

I have Tables; Category, Subject.

```
Category -> id, name, desc; 
Subject -> id, name, desc, category_id;
```

They are offering discounts for combination of number of subjects taken under categories.
For example.

```
Category Table (id, name)
1, Language
2, Cultural
3, Music

Subject table (id, name, category_id)
1, English, 1
2, Tamil, 1
3, Bharatham, 2
4, Violin, 3
5, Keyboard, 3
```

If a student is taking Subjects English, Tamil, Violin, then the combination is 2 Language and 1 Music. Likewise we have to record many combinations, and each has different discount amounts. How can I create combination table with number of categories and discount?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues, creating the discount table and then using it.  I would suggest a mostly normalized approach, which involves two tables:

```
create table Discounts (
    DiscountId int,
    DiscountRate float,
    NumCategories int
    . . .
)

create table DiscountCategories (
    DiscountCategoryId int,
    CategoryId int,
    MinCount int
)
```

The first describes each discount, the second has call the categories.  The first also has the column "NumCategories".  This is a deviation from strict normalization, but a big convenience in queries.

Let me assume that you have a table called `StudentSubjects`.  To find the applicable discounts:

```
select s.StudentName, d.DiscountId
from (select s.StudentName, ss.CategoryId, count(*) as numCategories
      from StudentSubjects ss join
           Subjects s
           on ss.SubjectId = s.id
     ) s left outer join
     DiscountCategories dc
     on s.CategoryId = dc.CategoryId and
        s.NumCategories >= dc.MinCount left outer join
     Discounts d
     on dc.DiscountId = d.DiscountId
group by s.StudentName, d.DiscountId
having count(ss.CategoryId) = max(d.NumCategories)
```

The first subquery summarizes the student courses by category.  It then finds the applicable discounts for each subject.  The final aggregation makes sure that all categories are covered for the discount.